# stop code if the condition is true

Tags: java

the problem is at the while loop, there is a comment

```
BufferedReader user = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
        "C:\\Users\\Ionut\\workspace\\tBot\\persoane.txt"));

String line;
while ((line = user.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.toLowerCase().contains(nume.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println("Ce mai faci " + nume + "?");
        ceva = scanIn.nextLine(); //here i want to stop if the condition is true, but it will show the message and go ahead and execute the rest of the code
    }
}
```

Comment: have you heard about the **break** keyword ? You want to break the loop not the if condition.

Comment: yes i know about the break, i formed my question wrong and i couldnt put more code to be more clear, but i solved it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically two common solutions:

1- Using `break`:

```
while ((line = user.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.toLowerCase().contains(nume.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println("Ce mai faci " + nume + "?");
        ceva = scanIn.nextLine(); 
        break;  // exists the closest loop
    }
}
```

2- Using a `boolean` flag:

```
boolean stop = false;
while (!stop && (line = user.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.toLowerCase().contains(nume.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println("Ce mai faci " + nume + "?");
        ceva = scanIn.nextLine();
        stop = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: +2: System.exit(0) or throw new RuntimeException()

Comment: No, Exceptions should not be used as flow of control. And System.exit is not really a way of exiting a loop. Otherwise I am sorry I forgot to mention to press the power button...

Comment: in my case, the second solution worked out, i had to adapt it to the rest of code, but now works as i want. thanks :)